# undefined is not an object(evaluating 'RNFSFileTypeRegular')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to import react-native-fs to download files to mobilephones. After I follow the lead to install and create the helloworld project, I meet this problem.How can I avoid this??Thx!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
    Alert
} from 'react-native';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

export default class test2 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.android.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,{'\n'}
          Shake or press menu button for dev menu333333
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not configure `native` part. You should run command `react-native link react-native-fs` or if it's not working try to do it [manually](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#usage-android). Don't forget to recompile and restart your whole project. If it didn't help, give us more information about your stack, are you using CRNA, did you eject it? What RN version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

do it before react-native link then do it react-native run-ios